# Batch insert/update query in JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-batch

I am using JPA 1.0 in my spring based web application. I have an enity list which is to be inserted/updated as a batch. I know,

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...
for (....) {
  ps.setString(..);
  ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();
```

I want to know if there exists any way to get the preparedStament object from Spring's JPATemplate or any alternate way

Answer (score 0):

Most JPA providers support batch writing, normally through a persistence unit property,

For EclipseLink use,

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
```

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_jdbc_batchwriting.htm#CIHIAGAF

Comment: Thanks James..however I am using Hibernate JPA..any link for that?